# Slow mounting of Docker volumes with large number of files on Linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose, coreos

We are experiencing some very strange behaviour when mounting volumes with large amount of data (e.g a million files )

The current setup:

- Docker host: Container Linux by CoreOS 1465.7.0 (Ladybug)
- Docker version client: 18.06.1-ce
- Docker version host: 17.09.0-ce

I have tried different versions of docker and CoreOs, both newer and older releases without any differences.
The data-directory on the docker-host is probably mapped to some storage tech, im not sure about the setup here, but I can fill out with details if necessary, but from my point of view it looks like a normal folder.

The initial error happened when switching from an anonymous volume mounted through a dummy-container (docker-compose v1) to a named volume (docker-compose v3). After creating a named volume, i shut down the docker-service and does a manual copy of the files from the old volume to the new volume. This has been tested with small data amounts, and that works so it doesnt seem to be an issue with the actual moving data in the internal /var/lib/docker-domain. I am also able to recreate this issue with a new installation where I copy a decently large amount of data.

Building container with compose works fine:

```
myservice:
  build: myservice
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: repo
      target: /home/repo

volumes:
  repo:
```

The repo-volume beeing the volume with a lot of data. Now, when trying to up the services, I get a timeout on the up, and the service gets stuck in "Created":

```
ERROR: for my-servce-new_exp_1  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxx.xx.xxx.xxx', port=2376): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

ERROR: for exp  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', port=2376): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.

If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

I have tried to increase the timeout, but something I get another timeout after a while.

Now, if I RESTART the docker-service or host now, the service is getting up and running (but doing it this way causes issues with internal dns-mappings between services)

If i up the service with an empty / small volume, it works as expected.

As a curiosity, I found something possibly releated when trying to mount the same volume to a docker-container:

```
docker run -it --rm --name rmytest --volume my-service-new_repo:/data ubuntu:latest
```

This will time out after e.g 30 minutes or so.

If I, on the other hand, adds any option to the consistency-parameter of the volume-mapping, it runs within a couple of seconds:

```
docker run -it --rm --name rmytest --volume my-service-new_repo:/data:consistent ubuntu:latest
```

I have had no success adding the same options to the compose files either, e.g

```
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: repo
    target: /home/repo
    consistency: delegated
```

Yields the same results; timeout and not working. Any help and pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: After a lot of research, this seems to be related to SeLinux and labelling of data when mounting. The conclusion is still not final, I will post the answer when its ready.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my own comment, this was due to SeLinux and labeling of date when mounting. To avoid this issue, we had to turn of the labeling:

```
 mycontainer:
    build: mycontainer
    restart: always
    # To avoid issue with named volume and mounting time
    security_opt:
      - "label=disable"
```

Disclaimer: Im not 100% sure about the full consequences of using this option, but in our situation this was the feasible way of solving this for now.

Comment: Would this be the same issue for bind mounts?

Comment: This appears to have stopped working in Docker 19.03. Open (at the time I posted this) issue at https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1000.